# error on running node.io via commandline on windows server 2008

Tags: node.js, node.io

Am getting the following error on running node.io via command line

[image]

Comment: Have you used node or any module in node before ? Did you install node.io

Comment: @user568109 yes i have installed node.io. and yes i have other modules installed too

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried a couple of things.  It seems Windows 7 had a problem with the command file name itself (node.io.cmd).  If you copy this command to something without the period (ie. nodeio.cmd), then I could successfully invoke the tool using "nodeio" instead of "node.io".

The file that would need to be changed was in my %APPDATA%\npm directory.  My %APPDATA% environment variable was mapped to "C:\Users{my user name}\AppData\Roaming".